# DataGridView Cell Focus

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm making an application with windows forms and a DataGridView but have a little problem here.

I've tried a couple of things but it seems that I can't remove this focus around the Selected Cell (Dotted line).

[image]

And I'd like to make it look like this when the row is clicked:

[image]

Just simply remove the dotted line all together from DGV. Is it possible?

Row selection is set to FullRowSelect, TabStop is False, MultiSelect is False. I've also tried with e.PaintParts in CellPainting to no avail. Any hints?

Comment: Do you allow to move from Cell to Cell using the TAB key (i.e., `StandardTab = false`)? If not, you could use SendMessage to send [`WM_CHANGEUISTATE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/wm-changeuistate) with mask  `(UISF_HIDEACCEL | UISF_HIDEFOCUS << 16) | UIS_SET` in the Enter event of the DGV. This disables focus cues. Otherwise, you need a Custom Control, derived from DataGridView, to override ShowFocusCues (e.g., `protected override bool ShowFocusCues => false;`)

Comment: StandardTab is already set to false. I'm a bit confused by the SendMessage part so I chose to try the DGV Custom Control to set ShowFocusCues to false. Now, when I start the application it works just fine until Tab is pressed anywhere on the form, then it shows Cues again and sometimes when I start the application it works just fine, sometimes it just doesn't (even without Tab pressed). I'm a bit confused of what is going on o.O

Comment: `StandardTab` should be set to `true` (to TAB outside the Control instead of moving the Focus to the next Cell). Try to set this in the Enter event of your DGV: `SendMessage([DataGridView].Handle, WM_CHANGEUISTATE, (IntPtr)((3 << 16) | 1), IntPtr.Zero);`, where `WM_CHANGEUISTATE = 0x0127` (with `StandardTab = true`).

Comment: I just tried, every line in that code is underlined with red, doesn't exist in the current context. I've never used SendMessage before, I might be doing something wrong here  because I just pasted your code to Enter event. Do I have to create SendMessage variable first?

Comment: [SendMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendmessage) is a Win32 function, you have to PInvoke it: `using System.Runtime.InteropServices; [...] [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)] internal static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint uMsg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);`

Comment: I managed to PInvoke the function but I still get errors with SendMessage part of the code, I think I need to do a bit more research of how I need to implement that function before I bore you with me being a newbie here. Thank you again for trying to help!

Comment: There's nothing specific you need to do, just add `using System.Runtime.InteropServices;` on top of your form class, the function declaration anywhere in the Form's class body (for now), then call the function wherever in that Form. You also need to add `private const uint WM_CHANGEUISTATE = 0x0127;`, as mentioned. -- BTW, since you have a Custom Control derived from DataGridView, try to add `protected override bool ShowKeyboardCues => false;`, I don't remember which one is more relevant in this context (I'm nowhere near a Windows machine right now, I'll test it when I can).

Comment: I did exactly what you've said I need to do and I'm still getting an error in the line of code. SendMessage([DataGridView].Handle, WM_CHANGEUISTATE, (IntPtr)((3 << 16) | 1), IntPtr.Zero); 'No corresponding arguments for hWnd...' and other ints, I have to be doing something wrong here but I'm not sure what exactly. Still no success with ShowKeyboardCues aswell.

Comment: C'mon, `[DataGridView]` means *the instance of your DataGridView object*. If you have a DataGridView named `dataGridView1`, then `SendMessage(dataGridView1.Handle, WM_CHANGEUISTATE, (IntPtr)((3 << 16) | 1), IntPtr.Zero);`, IF you have declared `WM_CHANGEUISTATE` as described.

Comment: Fml.. I did change [DataGridView] with my instance of DGV but I didn't remove square brackets.. Working on a multiple projects at once and my head isn't exactly clear I guess. Sorry to waste you more time than needed, it works like a charm now. Thank you a lot Jimi, I appreciate your effort, really. I'll have to take a closer look at SendMessage function in the future.

Answer (score 2):

The only thing that worked for me was to create a custom control that inherits from DataGridView and then override the ShowFocusCues like this:

```
protected override bool ShowFocusCues
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```